# After upgrading to Lumen 5.5 only "/" rout works and .htacess is not parsed from the app

Tags: php, routes, lumen

After upgrade my lumen project to 5.5 from 5.3 I have a problem with the routing of my application.

I made all the necessary changes on my app.php

```
$app->router->group([
  'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
  ], function ($router) {
  require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});
```

and then update the web.php like the following format

```
$router->get("/", function () use ($router) {
  return "root endpoint";
});


$router->post("/auth/login", 'Controller@login');
```

The problem now is that the the app forward all the requests to the "/" endpoint. For example the `www.api.com/auth/login` request will have a "root endpoint" response.

Also if I remove the root endpoint I will have a `NotFoundHttpException`

I am using `php 7` on `php build-in server`. Tests made through `Postman`

**Update**

After some search I manage to see that the .htacess file is not parsed at all. I came to this conclusion after I add a dump string on the begging of the `public/.htacess` file and instead of getting an `Internal Server Error` I keep getting the `"/"` endpoint's response. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to run `php artisan route:clear` in your terminal ?

Comment: unfortunately Lumen does not provide such commands

Comment: Not in Lumen, but in you terminal ! Read about [Flushing The Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0) section

Comment: The link you send is for the laravel upgrading. Lumen app can not follow all the instructions there because some things in Lumen are not done with the same way....like the `artisan` commands

Comment: Cause documentation sent me on Laravel doc. D̶i̶d̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶p̶a̶s̶s̶ ̶v̶i̶a̶ ̶L̶u̶m̶e̶n̶ ̶5̶.̶4̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶u̶p̶g̶r̶a̶d̶e̶ ̶?̶ I've installed a fresh installation of Lumen 5.3 then go directly to 5.5, and having no problems, maybe it is elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The description of the situation suggest that the rewrite rules are not applied. The rewrite rules in `.htaccess` are only applied if `mod_rewrite` is enabled by

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

(afterwards you have to restart apache2)